# Which image format (jpg,gif,png etc.) is supported by most android devices by default?

Tags: android, image, file-format

I am creating an android app which displays images, but I am confused that which image format images I should use. My mobile device shows jpg and png format images but not gif. Also, there might be some mobiles which show gif images but not jpg without the user needing to download something to show those images.

Which image format (jpg,gif,png etc) is supported by most android devices by default? Which image format images should I use in my app?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html), these formats are supported on Android:

```
JPEG (.jpg)     
GIF     
PNG     
BMP     
WebP
HEIF
```

Answer (score 2):

- JPEG (.jpg)
- GIF (.gif)
- PNG (.png)
- BMP (.bmp)
- WebP (.webp)

or might as well refer to this link to know more about android supported media formats.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) to see the supported formats. From my experience I can say that jpg and png is supported in all android version. GIF is supported in Kitkat but not sure about below it.

Answer (score 0):

- JPEG (.jpg)
- GIF (.gif)
- PNG (.png)
- BMP (.bmp)
- WebP (.webp) (Android 4.0+)
  (Lossless, Transparency, Android 4.2.1+)